# Regex to strip lat/long from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, geospatial

Anyone have a regex to strip lat/long from a string? such as:

ID: 39.825 -86.88333

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var latlong = 'ID: 39.825 -86.88333';

var point = latlong.match( /-?\d+\.\d+/g );

//result: point = ['39.825', '-86.88333'];
```

Comment: @Detroitpro - make sure to add a -? in front of the first \d to get negative values as well.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include Sean's absolutely correct suggestion

Answer (score 8):

To match one value

```
-?\d+\.\d+
```

For both values:

```
(-?\d+\.\d+)\ (-?\d+\.\d+)
```

And if the string always has this form:

```
"ID: 39.825 -86.88333".match(/^ID:\ (-?\d+\.\d+)\ (-?\d+\.\d+)$/)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function parseLatLong(str) {
    var exp = /ID:\s([-+]?\d+\.\d+)\s+([-+]?\d+\.\d+)/;

    return { lat: str.replace(exp, "$1"), long: str.replace(exp, "$2") };          
}

function doSomething() {
    var res = parseLatLong("ID: 39.825 -86.88333");

    alert('Latitude is ' + res.lat + ", Longitude is " + res.long);
}
```